# Thin LoadError: no such file to load thin_parser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thin

I have installed thin and try to do `thin start`, which end up with this error

```
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.8-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/thin_parser (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.8-x86-mingw32/lib/thin.rb:48:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.8-x86-mingw32/lib/thin.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.8-x86-mingw32/bin/thin:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby192/bin/thin:19:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby192/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help me out please, thanks in advance

Comment: What are the gems installed on system and used in your application?

Comment: @Nazar Sorry, I haven't reply quick enough, but since bunter have helped me already, do you still want the gem list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the output denotes a directory called `1.9` i.e.

`<ruby_install_dir>/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.8-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/`

*Note: My thin version is 1.2.10. In the following i will use the path as it appears on my system.*

For some reason the thin gem doesn't come with this directory. But a file called `thin_parser.so` resides in the parent directory `<ruby_install_dir>/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.10/lib/`

So my first solution was to create a directory `1.9` and copy the file thin_parser.so to it.
Now `thin start` works for me.

Alternatively you can edit the file `<ruby_install_dir>/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.10/lib/thin.rb` and change

```
if Thin.win?
  # Select proper binary under Windows
  major_ruby_version = RUBY_VERSION[/^(\d+\.\d+)/]
  require "#{Thin::ROOT}/#{major_ruby_version}/thin_parser"
else
  require "#{Thin::ROOT}/thin_parser"
end
```

to

```
if Thin.win?
  # Select proper binary under Windows
  major_ruby_version = RUBY_VERSION[/^(\d+\.\d+)/]
  require "#{Thin::ROOT}/thin_parser"
else
  require "#{Thin::ROOT}/thin_parser"
end
```

or even simpler

```
require "#{Thin::ROOT}/thin_parser"
```

I'm not sure what workaround is the better one, since i don't know what else files thin expects in the not existing directory. I don't know either where the Thin.win? fork becomes important.

I decided in favor of the first solution. But both ways fixed the Problem for me.

Best regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error when running `rake db:migrate`  (I suspect thin start would have given me the same error.)

I'm running on Amazon Linux (rpm based, so similar to CentOS and Redhat).   I had previously installed thin as root (gem install thin).  Although it may be irrelevant to your situation, just for completeness, I had also installed eventmachine using:

```
gem install eventmachine --platform=ruby
```

Here is the error I got:

```
% rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- thin_parser
/home/rails/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
etc. etc.
```

Based on the above information, I ran rake under strace and discovered that it was looking for thin_parser.so in the wrong place.  I was able to fix the problem by installing this symbolic link (I did this as root since I installed thin as root).  Obviously, adjust the path to where your version of thin is installed:

```
 cd /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib
 ln -s ../ext/thin_parser/thin_parser.so .
```

*Poof!*  That fixed it for me.