# Thin web server refuses to run in Windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, webserver, thin

I have taken a project from Github and can't make it working in Windows 7 x64.

When I attempt to start a debugger in RubyMine, I am getting this:

```
runnerw.exe C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/bin/rdebug-ide --dispatcher-port 19743 --port 19744 -- D:/Work/angular-devise/script/rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta14, ruby-debug-base 0.11.30.pre10) listens on 127.0.0.1:19744
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- thin_parser
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'block in require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in 'load_dependency'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin.rb:39:in '<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in 'block (2 levels) in require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in 'each'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in 'block in require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in 'each'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in 'require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in 'require'
    D:/Work/Paul/Documents/PROGRAMM/Hill30/Projects/trainer-common/StringsEditor/angular-devise/config/application.rb:13:in '<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in 'require'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in 'tap'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in '<top (required)>'
    D:/Work/Paul/Documents/PROGRAMM/Hill30/Projects/trainer-common/StringsEditor/angular-devise/script/rails:6:in 'require'
    D:/Work/Paul/Documents/PROGRAMM/Hill30/Projects/trainer-common/StringsEditor/angular-devise/script/rails:6:in '<top (required)>'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

if I attempt to run the application with `rails server` command, I get this:

```
D:\Work\angular-devise>rails server
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'require': cannot load such file -- thin_parser (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in 'load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin.rb:39:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in 'block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in 'each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in 'block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in 'each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in 'require'
        from D:/Work/Paul/Documents/PROGRAMM/Hill30/Projects/trainer-common/StringsEditor/angular-devise/config/application.rb:13:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in 'block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in 'tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in '<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in 'require'
        from script/rails:6:in '<main>'
```

and have no clue what to do. Google doesn't know about this error. Could you guide me during eleiminating the error?

Thin 1.5.0 is installed.

Comment: @David Stratton: The error you referred (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380826/thin-loaderror-no-such-file-to-load-thin-parser) is different.

Answer (score -1):

I had quite a bit of trouble setting up a dev environment on Windows myself. This error is only the first you'll be seeing of many (that's my guess, at least).

My solution was to set up Ubuntu in VirtualBox and install everything (including RubyMine) there. It works perfectly, and is a joy to use. As a bonus, I can save the machine state whenever I'm done coding, and when I get back to work, everything's right there exactly as I left it.

The actual files I work with are in a folder shared between my VM and my "real" machine, so the backup system for my computer backs them up automatically (in addition to pushing up to BitBucket).

Some people also use [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) to quickly create development VMs which let you keep using Windows (because you only need to SSH into your VM, and can keep editing files on Windows). A matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: Oh, for sure. That's what I'm saying: Ruby on Windows is just unexpected. I've had a project I used across multiple computers and it gave me not end of trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use 'bundle exec rails s' to launch the server.